# Best approach to display all the users who have more than 1 purchases in a month in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables in an Oracle Database, one of which is all the purchases done by all the customers over many years (`purchase_logs`). It has a unique `purchase_id` that is paired with a `customer_id`.The other table contains the user info of all the customers. Both have a common key of `customer_id`.

I want to display the user info of customers who have more than 1 unique item (NOT the item quantity) purchased in any month (i.e if A customer bought 4 unique items in february 2020 they would be valid as well as someone who bought 2 items in june). I was wondering what should my correct approach be and also how to correct execute that approach.

The two approaches that I can see are

**Approach 1**

Count the overall number of purchases done by all customers, filter the ones that are greater than 1 and then check if they any of them were done within a month.
Use this as a subquery in the where clause of the main query for retrieving the customer info for all the `customer_id` which match this condition.

This is what i've done so far,this retrieves the customer ids of all the customers who have more than 1 purchases in total. But I do not understand how to filter out all the purchases that did not occur in a single arbitrary month.

```
SELECT * FROM customer_details
WHERE customer_id IN (
SELECT cust_id from purchase_logs
group by  cust_id
having count(*) >= 2);
```

**Approach 2**

Create a temporary table to Count the number of monthly purchases of a specific user_id then find the MAX() of the whole table and check if that MAX value is bigger than 1 or not. Then if it is provide it as true for the main query's where clause for the customer_info.

Approach 2  feels like the more logical option but I cannot seem to understand how to write the proper subquery for it as the command `MAX(COUNT(customer_id)) from purchase_logs` does not seem to be a valid query.

This is the DDL diagram.

[image: DDL UML Diagram]

This is the Sample Data of `Purchase_logs`

[image: Purchase Logs]

`Customer_info`

[image: Customer Info]

and `Item_info`

[image: Item Info]

and the expected output for this sample data would be

[image: Expected Output]

It is certainly possible that there is a simpler approach that I am not seeing right now.
Would appreciate any suggestions and tips on this.

Comment: edit the question and show all table DDL, and sample data, expected output, please.

Comment: Should this *single arbitrary month* be the same for all customers or it may be any month for any customer?

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have added the required tables in the edit. I hope they are satisfactory.

Comment: @forpas that is the main issue here, that month can be any month for any customer.
So I cannot hardcode any specific month for everyone. Any two or more purchase in any month by a customer is to be considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cust_id 
FROM purchase_logs
GROUP BY cust_id, TO_CHAR(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MON')
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) > 1;
```

to get all the `cust_id`s of the customers *who have more than 1 unique item purchased in any month* and you can use with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer_details
WHERE customer_id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT cust_id -- here DISTINCT may be removed as it does not make any difference when the result is used with IN
  FROM purchase_logs
  GROUP BY cust_id, TO_CHAR(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MON')
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT item_id) > 1
);
```

Comment: This is neat, too.

Comment: Thank you so much  this worked for me !
Can I ask how did the `GROUP BY TO_CHAR()` worked to get the desired output ? I am not that versed in sql, so I did not knew it would be this easy. I was thinking I might have to do a subquery inside a subquery haha.

Comment: @udbhavshrivastava `GROUP BY cust_id, TO_CHAR(purchase_date, 'YYYY-MON')` groups the rows of `purchase_logs` by user and month (all months for each user) and because of the having clause you get in the results only the users who have purchased in any month at least 2 distinct items.

Comment: Ah I see, so If I am understanding this right the having clause works as a where condition on the smallest group segment made. In this case the smallest group being made is differentiated in the form of months.

Comment: ah my bad, I thought multiple answers could be accepted as valid. since the three answers all worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to display the user info of customers who have more than 1 purchases in a single arbitrary month.

Just add a `WHERE` filter to your sub-query.

So assuming that you wanted the month of July 2021 and you had a `purchase_date` column (with a `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type) in your `purchase_logs` table then you can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer_details
WHERE  customer_id IN (
         SELECT cust_id
         FROM   purchase_logs
         WHERE  DATE '2021-07-01' <= purchase_date
         AND    purchase_date < DATE '2021-08-01'
         GROUP BY cust_id
         HAVING count(*) >= 2
       );
```

---

If you want the users where they have bought two-or-more items in any single calendar month then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer_details c
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   purchase_logs p
         WHERE  c.customer_id = p.cust_id
         GROUP BY cust_id, TRUNC(purchase_date, 'MM')
         HAVING count(*) >= 2
       );
```

Comment: This looks like a really neat solution but unfortunately that month can be any month for any of the users i.e if a customer bought 5 items in march they are going to be valid as well as someone who bought 3 items in december. It has to be list of customers who bought two or more than two items in any month.
I apologize for not being clear there.

Comment: I tried this approach as well, and it worked !
thank you ^-^

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to try

```
with multiplepurchase as (
select customer_id,month(purchasedate),count(*) as order_count
from purchase_logs
group by customer_id,month(purchasedate)
having count(*)>=2)
select customer_id,username,usercategory
from mutiplepurchase a
left join userinfo b
on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @MT0 answer:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   customer_details CD
WHERE  exists (
         SELECT cust_id
         FROM   purchase_logs PL
         where CD.customer_id = PL.customer_id
         GROUP BY cust_id, item_id, to_char(purchase_date,'YYYYMM')
         HAVING count(*) >= 2
       );
```

Comment: `EXISTS` will be faster then `IN`

Comment: For some reason it gives me no rows with the current query but it works perfectly when I remove `item_id` from the `group by`
thank you !

Comment: It all depends how you want to count. If the rule is "an item twice in same month" then it should work. If the rule is "any two items in same month" then item_id should be indeed removed from the GROUP BY.